MapLibre : Issue with style.json and tiles vector declarations in HTML
As explained and asked in Slack Forum : https://osmus.slack.com/archives/C01G3D28DAB/p1721219062146369?thread_ts=1721213195.422509&cid=C01G3D28DAB
I want to use this TileServer: https://tileserver.linuxbabe.com/ with MapLibre
The style.json should be this: https://tileserver.linuxbabe.com/styles/basic-preview/style.json
and, based on https://tileserver.linuxbabe.com/data/v3.json
  ,
the tiles vector URL should be this: https://tileserver.linuxbabe.com/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf
But If I put those two URLs in their fields in the HTML, I do not get any output :

This is the complete map.html file :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Vector Tile Map with MapLibre</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
     <script src='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@latest/dist/maplibre-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@latest/dist/maplibre-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
     <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var map = new maplibregl.Map({
                container: 'map',
                style:
                    'https://tileserver.linuxbabe.com/styles
/basic-preview/style.json',
                    zoom: 5.43,
                    center: [-3.9, 54.5]
            });


            map.on('load', function () {
              // Add a new vector tile source with ID 'linuxbabe'.
              map.addSource('linuxbabe', {
                     'type': 'vector',
                     'tiles': [
                          'https://tileserver.linuxbabe.com/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
                      ],
                      'minzoom': 6,
                      'maxzoom': 14
                });
                map.addLayer(
                   {
                        'id': 'default', // Layer ID
                        'type': 'line',
                        'source': 'linuxbabe', // ID of the tile source created above
                           // Source has several layers. We visualize the one with name 'sequence'.
                        'source-layer': 'sequence',
                        'layout': {
                                  'line-cap': 'round',
                                  'line-join': 'round'
                         },
                        'paint': {
                                   'line-opacity': 0.6,
                                   'line-color': 'rgb(53, 175, 109)',
                                   'line-width': 2
                         }
                  },
               );
            });

            map.addControl(new maplibregl.NavigationControl());

            //set max zoom level (0-24)
            map.setMaxZoom(19);
    </script>
    </body>

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RaphyCollab/oq19abd4/2/
And here a jsbin repo : https://jsbin.com/dekujuz/edit?html,output
What am I missing and / or am I doing wrong?
